# Laravel 5.1: Using the Laravel IDE Helper Generator in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpstorm

I've installed the [Laravel IDE Helper Generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper). It works like a charm, its autocomplete is awesome, but I was wondering: is it also possible "jumping" to files directly?

For example, in `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Is it possible going to the view `welcome` directly (without having to navigate through the treeview and open it by double click)?

Comment: Not, it is not. Because `view` is a function, not a file.

Comment: Have you installed and configured **Laravel Plugin** ?

Comment: I'm running Win7 x64

Comment: You can press `shift key` twice and then write "welc" at popoup. It will take you to the file.

Comment: I found out that Ctrl+Shift+N opens a search dialog for files inside the projects, it also passes the "welcome" string to the dialog which is pretty nice as you can pick it pressing Enter .. would be perfect if this functionality would work with Ctrl-click on "welcome"

Answer (score 2):

it's possible by enabling the laravel plugin inside phpstorm:
Settings - Plugins
Then under Settings - Other Settings - Enable plugin for this project

Ctrl-Click on "welcome" -> opens welcome.blade.php

Voila! :)

Answer (score 1):

To navigate to a file inside your project as alternative i suggest:

> ⇧⌘O

To navigate to a class:

> ⌘O

To navigate t a symbol:

> ⌥⌘O

If you have a windows, just replace '⌘' to 'Ctrl'.

You can check for more [shortcuts and tips](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html).

Comment: But this is not answering the question :s

Comment: This is general navigation -- you still have to type file name/path. The OP, as I understood, have asked for much simpler and quicker -- just `Ctrl+Click` on "welcome" and corresponding file is opened (or possible alternatives offered).

Comment: its an alternative :/